# Something like OR operator in CLIPS (CLIPS Rule Based Programming Language)

Tags: conditional-statements, conditional-formatting, conditional-operator, clips

I need help with this program, I couldn't find out how to do that a user can input a yes/no for characters and I have defined a type of animal-like mammal - for mammal applies that milk character must be yes and legs(number of legs) can be 2 or 4 and another character can be yes or no like for example -
mammal - milk yes, legs 2 or 4, but backbone can yes or no, predator yes or no .... but I don't know how to do it (OR condition or idk something like that), user can input one of these its find out the type of animal which is defined in effects, thanks for help :)

```
;*********** DEFTEMPLATE ***********;
(deftemplate animal_type    
    (slot type (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols mammal bird fish))    
    (slot milk (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols yes no))  
    (slot feathers (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols yes no))  
    (slot fins (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols yes no))  
    (slot backbone (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols yes no))  
    (slot fly (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols yes no))   
    (slot predator (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols yes no))  
    (multislot legs (type INTEGER) (allowed-integers 0 2 4 6 8))
)

(deftemplate finding_type   
    (slot milk (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols yes no))  
    (slot feathers (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols yes no))  
    (slot fins (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols yes no))  
    (slot backbone (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols yes no))  
    (slot fly (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols yes no))   
    (slot predator (type SYMBOL) (allowed-symbols yes no))  
    (multislot legs (type INTEGER) (allowed-integers 0 2 4 6 8))
)

;*********** DEFFACTS ***********;
(deffacts characters_type   
    (animal_type (typ mammal) (milk yes) (legs 2 4))    
    (animal_type (typ bird) (milk no) (feathers yes) (fly yes)) 
    (animal_type (typ fish) (milk no) (feathers no) (fins yes) (legs 0))
)     
;something like this (animal_type (typ mammal) (milk yes) (backbone or(yes no)) ... (legs 2 4))

(deffacts temp_fact 
    (next_search)
)

(defrule input_characters   
    ?gone<-(next_search)
=>  (retract ?gone) 
    (printout t " " crlf)   
    (printout t "Enter - yes/no, legs - 0/2/4/6/8" crlf)    
    (printout t "==================================================================" crlf)
    (printout t "Milk:")    
    (bind ?o1 (read))
    (printout t "Feathers:")    
    (bind ?o2 (read))
    (printout t "Fins:")    
    (bind ?o3 (read))
    (printout t "Backbone:")    
    (bind ?o4 (read))
    (printout t "Fly:") 
    (bind ?o5 (read))
    (printout t "Predator:")    
    (bind ?o6 (read))
    (printout t "Legs:")    
    (bind ?o7 (read))

    (assert (finding_type (milk ?o1) (feathers ?o2) (fins ?o3) (backbone ?o4) (fly ?o5) (predator ?o6) (legs ?o7)) )
)

(defrule find_out_type  
    (finding_type (milk ?o1) (feathers ?o2) (fins ?o3) (backbone ?o4) (fly ?o5) (predator ?o6) (legs ?o7))
    (animal_type (type ?type) (milk ?o1) (feathers ?o2) (fins ?o3) (backbone ?o4) (fly ?o5) (predator ?o6) (legs ?o7))
=>  
    (printout t " " crlf)   
    (printout t "Type of animal is: " ?type crlf)
)   

(defrule not_found  
    (finding_type (milk ?o1) (feathers ?o2) (fins ?o3) (backbone ?o4) (fly ?o5) (predator ?o6) (legs ?o7))
    (not (animal_type (type ?type) (milk ?o1) (feathers ?o2) (fins ?o3) (backbone ?o4) (fly ?o5) (predator ?o6) (legs ?o7)) )
=>  
    (printout t " " crlf)   
    (printout t "Nothing found!" crlf)
)

(defrule cancel (declare (salience -10))    
    ?gone<-(finding_type (milk ?o1) (feathers ?o2) (fins ?o3) (backbone ?o4) (fly ?o5) (predator ?o6) (legs ?o7))
=>  
    (retract ?gone)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the animal_type pattern in your rules to use multifield wildcards to match extraneous values to the left and right of the specified number of legs. As your rules are currently the animal_type patterns will only be matched by facts containing exactly one value in the legs slot.

```
(animal_type (type ?type) 
             (milk ?o1) 
             (feathers ?o2) 
             (fins ?o3) 
             (backbone ?o4) 
             (fly ?o5) 
             (predator ?o6)
             (legs $? ?o7 $?))
```